# expo redownloads whole javascript bundle on every save

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, expo

as tittle suggests. every time i save my code instead of instant show up on screen as it was working before Expo re downloads the whole java script bundle again which takes a lot of time.
I have tried this command
 `npm start --reset-cache`
I have also restarted my pc but it didnt help.
i really need help regarding this as it is very time consuming
edit: my fast refresh is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@brentvatne posted the link to documentation above and after reading it i figured it out what was wrong. thank you @brentvatne.
So as mentioned in the documentation fast reload only works if the modules imported exists in the **same react tree** if they exists outside of that **react project directory** fast reload do not work and instead **there will be full reload of app**.so my express API actually existed outside the react tree at that time that's why it was re downloading the whole package on every save. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you should enable fast refresh in the development menu. every time you reload the app fully it will download the entire bundle. if you have fast refresh enabled and this is still happening then refer to the [fast refresh documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/fast-refresh) to learn more about why.

Comment: thankyou for replying so a weird this is happening as soon as i disable my fast refresh by shaking my device my app doesnt redownloads and refreshed is appeared at the bottom of my screen but this also doesnt make any changes in my app but if i enable fast refresh from there it redownloads the whole javascript bundle but in this case changes appear in the app